# Can I modify call audio stream in Android?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, alsa

I know that Android not permit this action. then I want to modify it's kernel.
I don't know that all hardware limited this action or no?
which hardware support this audio stream:

- mic->OS->baseband processor
- basband processor-> OS -> speaker

and not:

- mic->baseband processor && mic->OS
- basband processor-> speaker && baseband processor->OS

Comment: Please be more specific.  Posting code is best, with explanation.

Comment: I don't know that mobile SoC chip(ex: spnapdragon of qualcomm) allow to OS modifing audio stream or not.

Comment: It does allow software to modify the audio stream.  Look at OpenMAX and 'tunneled' vs. 'Non-tunneled'.  All of the user and kernel mode software is available in the Android tree and/or from codeaurora.org.

Comment: Ok, in media stream(ex. music playing) we can to modify, but in call audio stream, I am not sure. I think that mobile SoC creating direct path from Mic to DSP and from it to baseband processor. OS can config and control it but cannot modify audio stream. IS IT TRUE?

Comment: If the ALSA driver sets up a direct path between specific hardware components, then it is true that other software can not access that audio data.